# Find the largest number from a group of methods that return a number

Tags: java

I have a method called `FindBestMatch` and it calls another method named `compareMatrices` which is repeated ten times. `compareMatrices` basically does some math comparing two arrays and returns a number, the higher the number the better the two arrays match. `FindBestMatch` needs to return the value with the highest number.

Here's what I have:

```
public String FindBestMatch() {

    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("zero"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("one"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("two"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("three"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("four"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("five"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("six"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("seven"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("eight"), imgMatrix);
    compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix("nine"), imgMatrix);

}
```

So basically `FindBestMatch` runs for each number, zero through nine, and each times returns a number. I'm not sure how to find out which `compareMatrices` call returns the highest number?

EDIT

Here's `compareMatrices'. It takes as input a 2D array of number files, and a 2D array of an image file.

```
public double compareMatrices(int[][] num, double[][] img) {
    int nNumRows = num.length;
    int nNumCols = num[0].length;
    int nImgRows = img.length;
    int nImgCols = img[0].length;

    double highest = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < nImgRows - nNumRows + 1; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < nImgCols - nNumCols + 1; col++) {
            double score = 0;
            for 
            (int row_offset = 0; row_offset < nNumRows; row_offset++) {
                for (int col_offset = 0; 
                        col_offset < nNumCols; col_offset++) {
                    int imgRowIndex = row + row_offset;
                    int imgColIndex = col + col_offset;
                    int numV = num[row_offset][col_offset];
                    double imgV = img[imgRowIndex][imgColIndex];

                    if ((imgV == 1) && (numV == 1)) {
                        score +=1;
                    } else if ((numV == 1) & (imgV == 0)) {
                        score -= 0.25;
                    } else if ((numV == 0) && (imgV == 0)) {
                        score += 0.25;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score > highest) {
                highest = score;
            }
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

And it returns the score, basically the better the number matrix and the image matrix match, the higher the score.

Comment: What is `compareMatrices` ? Does it return something? What are its inputs?

Comment: Well, you could start by storing the returned value somewhere, such as in a variable, and then comparing one against another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you store the strings in an array `String[]` and use a for loop to find the maximum:

```
public String FindBestMatch() {
    String[] m = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    double max = compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix(m[0]), imgMatrix);
    double score = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 1 ; i < m.length ; i++) {
        score = compareMatrices(numFiles.getMatrix(m[i]), imgMatrix);

        if(score > max) {
            max = score;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return m[i];
}
```

The method would return the string with the highest score